# How set LLDB source-map when debugging in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk, lldb

I'm trying to use native debug in *Android Studio 2.3 Canary 2*; Gradle plugin is '*gradle:2.3.0-alpha2*'.
I took "hello-libs" sample from https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk. This sample uses CMake as external native build system. Okay, there are prebuilt libraries(libgmath.a and libgperf.so) in /hello-libs/distribution/. Libraries contain ***debug information***, they are ***not stripped***. 
I tried to native debug these prebuilt libraries with pointing lldb debugger on sources from my PC with command:

```
settings set target.source-map
```

So, I used

```
objdump -Wl
```

to get the path of source files which were used to build these libraries.
Objdump gave me next directories:

1. /Users/gfan/proj/android-mk/work-branch/hello-libs/gen-libs/src/main/cpp/gperf/src
2. /Users/gfan/proj/android-mk/work-branch/hello-libs/gen-libs/src/main/cpp/gmath/src

Okay, in debug configuration I added two commands in ***"LLDB Startup Commands"***

1. settings set target.source-map /Users/gfan/proj/android-mk/work-branch/hello-libs/gen-libs/src/main/cpp/gperf/src e:\WORKSPACE\hello-libs\gen-libs\src\main\cpp\gperf\src\
2. settings set target.source-map /Users/gfan/proj/android-mk/work-branch/hello-libs/gen-libs/src/main/cpp/gmath/src e:\WORKSPACE\hello-libs\gen-libs\src\main\cpp\gmath\src\

In tab "Symbol Directories" i set path to search debug symbols in:

1. E:\WORKSPACE\hello-libs\app.externalNativeBuild\cmake\debug\armeabi-v7a\CMakeFiles\hello-libs.dir
2. E:\WORKSPACE\hello-libs\app\build\intermediates\cmake\debug\obj\armeabi-v7a
3. E:\WORKSPACE\hello-libs\distribution\gmath\lib\armeabi-v7a
4. E:\WORKSPACE\hello-libs\distribution\gperf\lib\armeabi-v7a

I used only '***armeabi-v7a***' in ndk.abiFilters.

All debug configurations in Android Studio are really not obvious 
for me. So, my questions are:

- How to correctly set ***lldb source-map*** to debug prebuilt libraries with sources on my local machine?
- And BTW, who knows how to use ***"Host working directory:"*** in debug configurations? There is only one line about it on https://developer.android.com/studio/run/rundebugconfig.html and it sounds "Specify the LLDB working directory." How should i specify it?

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I have my sources in a specific directory, but I don't know how to make LLDB aware of it. Debugging native code works, but it cannot find the `.cpp` files so it doesn't step into methods.